# Google font weight is applied even if I do not include

Tags: css, fonts, typography, google-fonts

Does anybody can explain me, why do I have bold fonts on my website even that I did not import bold variants? This is my link.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
```

Even when I have this link, I can use bold variants. Do browser apply some native bold variants? Where is the magic?

Also, when I import font **weight** for bold variant with this code above, the bold font vizual is different - I think that is beacuase the real **weight** is imported.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Can somebody explain me this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to import to have bold fonts, becuase css can make the font bold. But you are right when you import bold fonts, its the fonts own bold. css has the same bold for every font

Answer (score 0):

Double check your CSS code. And in Chrome's DevTools. There should be no magic. If you really haven't specified its weight anywhere - go try to specify it as you need. If nothing helps, you can download the exact font you need and include it as a custom font using @font-face as in [this tutorial](https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website) e.g.

Also when you open the link https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro directly in the browser you can see there only one weight:

```
font-weight: 400;
```